# How to calculate geography st_distance in EF?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework

I try to calculate geography distance usinq NpSql in EF, but returned result is always as geometry.

```
NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate coordinate1 = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate(12.25, 51.25);                       
NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point point1 = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point(coordinate1);
point1.SRID= 4326;

NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate coordinate2 = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate(12.50, 51.25);
NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point point2 = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point(coordinate2);
point2.SRID = 4326;

Console.WriteLine(point1.Distance(point2));
```

1. Create coordinates
2. Then new point
3. Set SRID

Answer (score 0):

Finally, wrote new class and by Haversine formula i calculated geography distance

```
 public static class Distance
{

    
    /// <summary>
    /// Distance on a sphere: The Haversine Formula
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>distance in meters</returns>
    public static double Haversine(Coordinate coordinateFirstPoint, Coordinate coordinateSecondPoint)
    {
        // Coordinate (longitude, latitude)

        double earthRadius = 6371008.7714;

        double temp = Math.Acos(Math.Sin(Math.PI * coordinateFirstPoint.Y / 180) * Math.Sin(Math.PI * coordinateSecondPoint.Y / 180) + 
            Math.Cos(Math.PI * coordinateFirstPoint.Y / 180) * Math.Cos(Math.PI * coordinateSecondPoint.Y / 180) * Math.Cos(Math.PI * coordinateFirstPoint.X / 180 - Math.PI * coordinateSecondPoint.X / 180));
        
        return temp*earthRadius;
    }
}
```